# OSX10.11 DiskUtility v.15 bug in SDXC card access?

Tags: disk-utility, osx-el-capitan, sdxc

OSX10.11 has DiskUtility v.15 and when trying "Info", "FirstAid", or "Erase" the SDXC card in the SD access slot; these functions never finish - therefore can't Quit Diskutility - only way to stop is Force Quit !? Looks like bug to me, but Apple.com support draws a blank?

Comment: Sounds more like the card has had it to me. How many cards have you tried? BTW, Disk Utility 'the app' is just a front for the underlying unix-like diskutil underneath, so force-quitting it may not always do what you think. Reboot before further testing.

Answer (score 0):

contacted Apple Corp Chat. Since iMac 27" Retina, and SDXC, and OSX 10.11.2 are brand new (less than 2 weeks) there couldn't be any thing "bad", yes? Apple chat drew a blank - had me try a bunch of "things" to no avail. Out of desperation they said to "Reset SMC". Asked: How?. They said shut down iMac 27", then pull power cord from back of iMac. Wasn't sure to do it. After end of chat, tried to use diskutil on some other Disks attached to USB chain ... and none of them were accessible either. So shut down iMac gracefully and pulled power cord. Restart and all Disks worked again. BTW: the built-in SD card slot is NOT QUITE Compatible with Diskutility: First Aid failes on SD card in built-in slot and Diskutil fails to eject SDXC card; BUT plugged same SDXC card on USB multiformat adapter and Diskutil can do First Aid and Eject just fine.......